# PSpice models for BC547C, BC557C, BF245A, BC548C and BD135-16

Tags: transistors, spice, orcad, model

I'm trying to make this circuit in OrCAD Capture CIS to simulate it in spice:
[image]

I found the resistors and capacitors in the ANALOG library. I also found all the transistors, except Q3, in the TRANSISTOR library but none of them has a SPICE model so i can't make simulations. What can i do?
I found some transistors in the EVAL library but it is not what i am looking for

Comment: This sounds like a question best suited for the suppliers of OrCAD.

Comment: Just a comment on your circuit. A BF245A's Idss has about a 3.2:1 range, with ~3.6mA as the mid value. Won't this be a rather wide spread in the operational point ? Was there a reason for not using a suitably biased BJT here ?

Comment: Something else. The BDxxx transistors are not well parametrically specced. You may have trouble finding a model. Most designers stopped using them about 30 years ago ! The same applies to the 'popular' TIPxx transistors. It might make sense to use a more modern device. BC547, BC557 etc are 'jellybean' small signal silicon devices. Almost any similar part will substitute in the real world or for simulation. I'd substitute BC184 and BC214 here if you can use them. https://www.pspice.com/model-library/filter?combine=ge&page=31

Comment: ON Semi has a model for this, but I suggest reading the warnings in the previous comments before proceeding: https://www.onsemi.com/support/design-resources/models?rpn=BD13516

Comment: @GrahamStevenson silly question but, how do i download the models from the link you sent ? Also, i'm not sure if there was a reason for using B245.

Comment: https://www.pspice.com/how-download-pspice-models  Apparently it should already be in the Orcad library.

Answer (score 2):

```
        .model BF245A    NJF(Beta=1.754m Betatce=-.5 Rd=1 Rs=1 Lambda=2.667m Vto=-1.409
        +                Vtotc=-2.5m Is=33.57f Isr=322.4f N=1 Nr=2 Xti=3 Alpha=311.7
        +                Vk=243.6 Cgd=3.35p M=.3622 Pb=1 FC=.5 Cgs=3.736p KF=13.56E-18
        +                Af=1)
    *------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .MODEL BD139 NPN (IS=2.3985E-13 BF=244.9 NF=1.0 BR=78.11 NR=1.007 ISE=1.0471E-14
        +  NE=1.2 ISC=1.9314E-11 NC=1.45 VAF=98.5 VAR=7.46 IKF=1.1863 IKR=0.1445 RB=2.14 RBM=0.001
        +  IRB=0.031 RE=0.0832 RC=0.01 CJE=2.92702E-10 VJE=0.67412 MJE=0.3300 FC=0.5 CJC=4.8831E-11
        +  VJC=0.5258 MJC=0.3928 XCJC=0.5287 XTB=1.1398 EG=1.2105 XTI=3.0)
        *$
        *-------------------------------------------------------
        .MODEL BD140 PNP (IS=2.9537E-13 BF=201.4 NF=1.0 BR=23.765 NR=1.021 ISE=1.8002E-13 NE=1.5
        +  ISC=7.0433E-12 NC=1.38 VAF=137.0 VAR=8.41 IKF=1.0993 IKR=0.10 RB=1.98 RBM=0.01 IRB=0.011
        +  RE=0.1109 RC=0.01 CJE=2.1982E-10 VJE=0.7211 MJE=0.3685 FC=0.5 CJC=6.8291E-11 VJC=0.5499
        +  MJC=0.3668 XCJC=0.5287 XTB=1.4883 EG=1.2343 XTI=3.0)
        *$
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
.MODEL BC559C PNP (IS=10.2F NF=1 BF=650 VAF=98.6 IKF=60M ISE=2.02P NE=2
+ BR=4 NR=1 VAR=20 IKR=90M RE=0.515 RB=2.06 RC=0.206 XTB=1.5 XTF=50 Xti=3
+ CJE=7.46P VJE=1.1 MJE=0.5 CJC=5.21P VJC=0.3 MJC=0.3 TF=636P TR=442N)
*$

*----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
.model BC549C   NPN(Bf=490 Br=2.9 Cjc=5.5p Cje=12p Eg=1.1 Fc=.5 IkF=.1500 Ikr=6
+               Is=8f Isc=7p Ise=100f Itf=1.4 Mjc=.31 Mje=.7 Nc=1.5 Ne=1.8 
+               Nk=.63 Rc=1.12 Tf=420p Tr=10n Vaf=24 Vjc=.5 Vje=.5 Vtf=12
+               Xtb=1.5  Xtf=50 Xti=3)
*
*$
```

These models will do the job, just copy them into your EVAL library.